Struggling with Veracode flagging tableName-variable as "SQL Injection" flaw
We have a command-line utility program that loads the specified file (CSV) into the specified table.
Obviously, the table-name will be externally-provided (on command-line), and Veracode flags that as a possible SQL-injection vulnerability. For example, this line is flagged:
    private static String startingCntQry =
        "select count(*) as COUNTER from @TABLENAME";
...
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(startingCntQry.replace("@TABLENAME",
                tableName));


I understand the concern in theory -- but consider it inapplicable in this case: anyone able to invoke this utility already has the DB-credentials and can do whatever damage he wants directly. Still I need to make it go away.
The table-names cannot be a parameter for a PreparedStatement. There are suggestions, that the table-name should be checked against the list of existing tables, but our utility, depending on other command-line flags, might be creating the specified table anew -- it would not be on the list of the already existing ones.
Yes, we can check the specified name against some regular-expression, but would that satisfy Veracode?

In general, these tools are always going to have occasional false positives, and you should probably simply mark it as such, assuming you have a way to do so. You could remove "@TABLENAME" and append instead of replace, but I'm sure that would provoke the same complaint from Veracode.

I don't use Veracode, so I don't have personal experience to answer this. But a quick Google search I did finds a page with the regular expression method of validation, including a Java example here: https://community.veracode.com/s/article/how-do-i-fix-cwe-73-external-control-of-file-name-or-path-in-java Read the notes following the example for the process of approving the validation.

Thanks for the pointer, @BillKarwin. The page is not really applicable here, except for one bit: "While this code is recommended, it can not currently be automatically verified by Veracode Static Analysis and will require a manual review by someone from your organization (please note that Veracode does not approve or reject mitigation proposals)." So, whatever we do, a computer will not close the bogus "vulnerability" -- and we'll need to talk to people...

I read it that way too: that it will take human judgment to approve the solution. I think that's appropriate in some cases.

Why don't you use a tool from the database to perform that task? It depends a bit on the DB, but usually there exist such tools. If you need to prepare the data, your own CLI tool could do just the preparation and output that into another file that you then can use together with the DBs native tool.

Veracode is completely correct here: this is a possible source of SQL injection if you just look at the part in the Java code. You can either mitigate this attack vector by only having the name checked within your software to contain only "harmless" characters, or you ensure that an attacker never can call that CLI program.
Both cases probably cannot be verified with a static code analysis tool (maybe you could pass the check if you provide a limited preset of allowed tablenames and pick only one of them, but your description doesn't sound like this is feasible for your situation).
So it means, you will have to document the countermeasures and talk to somebody that can confirm that those are sufficient and create an exception to that static code analysis tools output. As such tools have quite some false positives usually this is a "normal" process, if your environment requires certain validation levels to be met.

Well, obviously, a human being could be convinced, that a particular finding is a false-positive. I was hoping for some way to convince the tool...

Looks like there is a whole process for doing this, according to the docs About mitigating flaws
